# WebApi Binding - Deserialize a part of the incoming json to JToken

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this json to a model:

```
{
"settings": [
    {
    "name": "setting1",
    "value": {
        "key": "value"
        }
    }, 
    {
    "name": "setting2",
    "value": 10
 }
]
}
```

As you can see, my `value` can be either a simple value, like an int, or string or it can be another json object.

My goal here is to deserialize the value into a `JToken` or a `string`.

I was trying out to deserialize using Json.NET as I know WebAPI uses it under the hood.

This is what I tried:

```
  public class SettingsBatch
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "settings")]
    public List<SettingInBatch> Settings { get; set; }
  }

  public class SettingsInBatch
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }
 }
```

From my tests (please read comments inline):

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public string Value { get; set; } // deserialization fails when "value" is a JsonObject

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public JToken Value { get; set; } // deserialization fails always

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public Object Value { get; set; } // deserialization works fine, what's curios 
// is that if the value is a json object the Object type is JToken 
// (just that I have to cast it). If it's an int or a string
// obviously the type is int / string so I would have to 
//construct somehow a JToken.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to read the Request contents as a string and then use `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`? Then you can do any manual JSON parsing with the payload string. It's handy when the incoming JSON does not have always the same "schema".

Comment: I haven't, I'm sure I can parse it in a custom way, I was wondering if there is a possibility to use the existing framework.